# Is there an API which mimic Share a file and define "People you chose" which can be new/existing external users?

Tags: sharepoint-online, development, sharepoint-rest-api, power-automate

Inside the SharePoint UI we can share a file with "People you chose" and we can define both internal users, new external users or existing external users, as follow:

[image]

Now I have a Power Automate flow and I want to share a file with internal and external users using the same approach. but seems Power Automate does not provide an out of the box action for this scenario, so can we use SharePoint REST API?

- Where I can share the file with internal/external

  - Get the file link

    - Send the link in an email

Is this possible? I do not want the Share action to send notification directly, I want to get the link and send it using another Send Email action?

Thanks.

Comment: Please check my answer [here](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/303243/sponline-how-to-generate-a-sharing-link-via-rest) where I provided api details. Here I mentioned how to use it in C# but you can use same API in Power Automate here as well. Let me know if works for you or not

Comment: I am checking to see how things are going there on this issue.

Answer (score 0):

You can refer to following api to get sharelink

```
 _api/web/lists/getbytitle('listtitle')/getitembyid(id)/sharelink
```