# Share a file with external users using anonymousAccess by using REST API

Tags: sharepoint-online, sharepoint-rest-api, anonymous-authentication, anonymous-access

After doing some research, I reached out the i can do the following POST request which will allow me to share a file with external users using anonymousAccess using SharePoint REST API:-

Method:- `POST`

URL:- `_api/web/Lists('ListGUID')/GetItemByID('1')?['ID']}')/Sharelink`

Body:-

```
{

    "request":{
        "createLink":true,
        "settings":{
            "allowAnonymousAccess":true,
            "linkKind":6,
            "role":1,
            "restrictShareMembership":false,
            "updatePassword":true,
            "password":"***",
            "scope":0
        }
    }
}
```

now in general the above will allow me to create an anonymous link with a password and with read-only permission, but i am confused on the other parameters, which are :-

- "linkKind"
- "restrictShareMembership"
- "updatePassword"
- "scope":0

so what are those parameters and what they represent inside the UI:-

[image]

Thanks

Comment: See similar thread at https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/303243/sponline-how-to-generate-a-sharing-link-via-rest

Comment: @KalpeshVaghela thanks for the link but from where you get the options for different links? as i did not find any official documentations regarding this