# Using SharePoint REST API can we create a share link for specific external user

Tags: sharepoint-online, development, sharepoint-rest-api, sharing

Using SharePoint REST API, i can do the following POST request to create an anonymous sharing link with password:-

1- Method:- POST

2- URL:- _api/web/Lists('ListGUID')/GetItemByID('1')?['ID']}')/Sharelink

3- Body:-

```
{

    "request":{
        "createLink":true,
        "settings":{
            "allowAnonymousAccess":true,
            "linkKind":6,
            "role":1,
            "restrictShareMembership":false,
            "updatePassword":true,
            "password":"***",
            "scope":0
        }
    }
}
```

this mimic this UI action for creating anonymous sharing link-

[image]

but how i can modify the Body parameters to create a link for specific users instead, which can be achieved from the UI using this action: -

[image]

any advice please?

Answer (score 2):

You you provide lists of users using `peoplePickerInput` property as shown in below:

{

```
"request":{
    "createLink":true,
    "peoplePickerInput":[ { "Key":"alexw@consto.com", "IsResolved":false },{ "Key":"miriamg@consto.com", "IsResolved":false } ]
    "settings":{
        "allowAnonymousAccess":true,
        "linkKind":6,
        "role":1,
        "restrictShareMembership":false,
        "updatePassword":true,
        "password":"***",
        "scope":0
    }
}
```

}

Please go through with below sample solution which I prepared in C# for same purpose. Here you can check what possible input we can provide for different scenario.

[Share Document with REST API - c#](https://github.com/kavaghela/sharedocumentspapi/blob/main/SP.ShareDocumentUsingRESTAPI/SP.ShareDocumentUsingRESTAPI/Program.cs)

**Similar Thread:**

[SPONLINE - How to generate a sharing link via REST?](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/303243/sponline-how-to-generate-a-sharing-link-via-rest)

Comment: ,, but you are passing 2 paramters that contradicts with each other ` "linkKind":6,
        "role":1,` am i correct? .. as linkkind=6 allow anonymousEdit while role=1 grant read-ony?? am i missing something?

Comment: also i do not want to create anonymous links, i want to create a link shared with specific users,, so i should pass ` "allowAnonymousAccess":false,`instead of ` "allowAnonymousAccess":true,`?

Comment: I have just provided my input how you can pass users as an sample

Comment: but i do not want to create anonymous links, i want to create a link shared with specific users,, so i should pass ` "allowAnonymousAccess":false,instead of  "allowAnonymousAccess":true,`? –

Comment: but i do not want to create anonymous links, i want to create a link shared with specific users,, so i should pass `"allowAnonymousAccess":false,` instead of `"allowAnonymousAccess":true,`?

Comment: also you are passing ` "allowAnonymousAccess":true,` but at the same time you are specifying a list of users to access the file.. so this is not anonymous anyone... am i correct? or i am missing something ?

Comment: also you code will raise this error `{
  "status": 400,
  "message": "An unexpected 'StartArray' node was found when reading from the JSON reader. A 'PrimitiveValue' node was expected.\r\nclientRequestId: e4cae5ae-226f-48c8-ac18-df3e5ba06739\r\nserviceRequestId: 9d34b2a0-207b-6000-8c33-34c32137ebe2",
  "source": "https://
****.sharepoint.com/sites/Certification/_api/web/Lists('d00b93fd-7af1-4985-ba4d-4d957b82f5b2')/GetItemByID('40')/Sharelink",
  "errors": [
    "-1",
    "Microsoft.Data.OData.ODataException"
  ]
}`

Comment: can you advice more on this please?